# Protractor: Issue using repeater and filter properly

Tags: javascript, protractor

I'm currently trying to iterate through a repeater and delete campaigns which have been created by my test. The name is passed in via the call from the spec file, it should then use this to filter any campaigns in the repeater, and select the delete button when one with that name is found, currently it doesn't seem to work, and I'm not sure why as I'm not getting any errors for element not found etc. Therefore I've assumed my logic is wrong.

I'm using the pageObject.js to support the spec.js file.

pageObject.js

```
this.campaignDelete = function(name) { // Currently not tested.     
        element.all('campaign in campaignsName').filter(function(item) {
            item.element(by.binding('campaign.Name')).getText().then(function(title) {
                item.foreach(function() {
                    if(title === name) {
                        this.delete = element(by.css('[ng-click="showDeleteCampaignModel(campaign)"]')).click();  
                        this.confirm = element(by.css('[ng-click="deleteCampaign()"]')).click();
                    } 
                });
            });
        });
    };
```

Spec.js

```
describe('Deletes the newly created campaign', function() {

    beforeEach(function() {
        browser.get(browser.params.urls.dashboard);
    });

    it('Should delete the newly created campaign', function() {
        campaignPage.campaignDelete(browser.params.campaign.name);
    });
});
```

Comment: You appear to be using protractor method in the code you're trying to test, not in the test itself. Are you sure that's what you want to be doing?

Comment: I haven't added a check to see if it was successfully deleted yet, just trying to actually get it deleting the row in the repeater. I'll add an expect after it works (I can manually see if it removes it)

Comment: That's what I'm saying; you're using test methods like `element.all` and `by.binding` in the functional element; those methods are only for testing.

Comment: They are being used for testing, it's testing if the elements exist on the page, then selecting the one it needs, then selecting the button attached to the element, deleting it, then testing if it was deleted successfully.

Comment: https://www.thoughtworks.com/insights/blog/using-page-objects-overcome-protractors-shortcomings

Comment: ahh, I see. It's not clear at all from your question that `pageObject.js` is being used as a test helper; I'd suggest you edit your question to include a reference to that design pattern.

Answer (score 0):

The second line in your code is missing the ***by.repeater*** locator strategy, it should be - `element.all(by.repeater('campaign in campaignsName')).filter(function(item) {`

You can directly get all the campaign name elements using - `element.all(by.repeater('campaign in campaignsName').column('campaign.Name'))`

[by.repeater](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ProtractorBy.prototype.repeater)

This below code should be able to return you the matching campaign.

```
 var reqcamp = element.all(by.repeater('campaign in campaignsName').column('campaign.Name')).filter(function(elem, index) {
      return elem.getText().then(function(text) {
        return text === name;
      });
    }).first();
```

I am not sure the delete statement ie. css part, is correct (not sure without html). Should it not include the relevant campaign to begin with, else it will just find the first matching element on the page.